# Administrative relations of a place with openstreetmap

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

I did a lot of research about how to use [overpass-api](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) tried a lot of things on http://overpass-turbo.eu/ but i can't find the way to get the result i'm expecting ...

I would like with a query, to find all the relations a place has but only administrative relations (department of the place, region of the place, country) everyhting that is assimilated to an "AdministrativeArea"

Tried this with both [nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and the [overpass_api](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide)

If any of you guys have an idea
Thanks !

Comment: boundary=administrative + admin_level?

Comment: I tried a lot of things with that but im not sure about the query i should write in http://overpass-turbo.eu/ could you give me an example please ? like if i wanted a list of administrative area for a city

Comment: when you go here http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=159257777 the "Address" table give exactly what i want, how can i get these informations with overpass-api please ?

Comment: Why can't you obtain the address information from Nominatim? Nominatim is a geocoder and specialized for address queries.

Comment: It does not return all the administrative area of a place, for example for France city i don't get the department only the region with "adressedetails=1" maybe i missed a parameter ... Btw can anyone explain the difference between Overpass-api and Nominatim i'm a bit confused ...

Comment: Are you sure that this missing region actually exists in OSM? Regarding the difference of those two APIs: Nominatim is mainly a geocoder. You can search for names, addresses and coordinates and it will return the full address hierarchy and location for each result. Overpass API instead is a tool for searching for *all* kinds of tags. However it has no knowledge of address hierarchies, it just returns the raw tags from OSM. See the various examples of those tools in the OSM wiki to get an idea about their usefulness.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help scai, yeah it exists, when i search for a town on http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ it gives me all the data about it but when i query it from my web app, the json returned is missing some things like the derpatment although the derpatment is in the 'Adress' table on details page on http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216709/address-feature-missing-in-nominatim-returned-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the following query to get the result:

```
is_in(45.6178738,4.6703107)->.a;
rel(pivot.a)[boundary=administrative];
out tags;
```

I used the center point `45.6178738,4.6703107` to get all relevant relations this point is contained in.

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jQS

Comment: Don't understand the query yet but i does work great ! Thanks a lot, it's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Ok, I should have added a bit of explanation: Line 1: Get all areas, where the location 45.61,4.67 is in and remember this result set in a variable *a*. Line 2: Turn areas back into ordinary OSM object "relation" and filter them according to the criterion `boundary=administrative`. Line 3: Output the results, only tags, but no relation members.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaination and query, I was convinced it was possible but did not figure out how for many days