# Get more details for given coordinates using overpass api

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am currently using this query ([API URL](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[place=%27county%27](around:20000.0,49.8728,8.6512);out;)) to get the county name from a coordinate.

```
[out:json];
node[place='county'](around:20000.0,49.8728,8.6512);
out;
```

I wish to have more details like state, city etc etc along with county. Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use `is_in` instead:

`is_in(49.8728,8.6512);
out;`

try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/k2p

Also see this very similar question: [Administrative relations of a place with openstreetmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432275/administrative-relations-of-a-place-with-openstreetmap)